# Windows GIT 2.20.0 how to split a folder into its own repo and keep history

Tags: windows, git, git-filter-branch

Windows Git 2.20.0
Using Bash (and windows command line git) both same result.

Is there an accepted and SAFE way to extract a folder from a large repository and move it into its own REPO whilst keeping the link back to the large repo for synchronizing back to the main code base?

```
GROUP
 Company1
   Apps
     SharedApp
 Company2
   Apps
```

I want to extract SharedApp out into its own repo but keep it linked with GROUP if possible.  so if someone checks out GROUP they get the whole lot, but a 3rd party Dev can check out just the Apps folder.

I have tried using:

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter SharedApp
```

but this just returns "Found nothing to rewrite"

I have also tried:

```
git subtree -P SharedApp -b newbranch
```

But this just puts the entire structure set on a new branch "newbranch" and doesn't filter anything as (I thought) the docs say it should.

Have considered using SubRepos but i hear they are particularly troublesome down the line.

Any help greatly appreciated.

edit: at some point i need to do this for a LOT of folder and libraries and link them back into the main repo. hence the question.

Comment: You want to use `git subtree split`

Comment: Thanks Phillippe, thought so.   In fact I've just done that (turns out you have to do a git subtree add first.  then split it.  so its now in a branch.  However, how do i then cut everything else out so that branch only contains SharedApp so i can i change its remote to its new home?   git filter-branch doesn't appear to be doing anything at all??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your emphasis on "SAFE".  You are using git - anything you do to a clone affects only that clone.  So long as you verify what you've done locally before affecting the remote, you shouldn't be able to lose anything.  What is the risk you're concerned about?

If you use `filter-branch`, you won't have an easy way to integrate future changes between the repos.  Not that there's no way to do it, but it requires jumping through significant hoops because the result is not linked to the original.

That said, if you want to use `filter-branch`:  One reason it would do that is if the path isn't specified correctly.  Make sure you're giving the full path from the worktree root, and depending on your file system capitalization may matter.  (On windows it doesn't normally matter; Mac or *nix it probably does.)  If there is a SharedApp directory with files in it committed directly under the repo root, the filter argument as given should be fine.

Also, you probably need to add a `--all` argument (or one or more branch names) so it knows what to rewrite.

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter SharedApp -- --all
```

In my opinion subrepos are the closest thing git offers to what you're asking for.  Yes, a lot of people don't like them; then again, a lot of other people use them just fine.  You have to take the time to understnad how to work with them, and not expect them to work a different way than they work, or else not use them.

Comment: Various blogs warn against Sub Repos as being very dangerous and pretty much guaranteed to cause havoc and pain down the line.  (not a great advert for them).

I might try a SubRepo on this particular task and see how it goes before jumping in.

Comment: @davec Various blogs say lots of things.  As I said above: they work if you learn how they're meant to be used and use them in that way.  Regardless, it is the feature git offers closets to what was requested.  If you don't like that feature, don't use it; but that doesn't mean there's magically going to be something else.

Comment: Mark, i find you attitude quite condescending and that is certainly not true at all.  There is now in the main git build subtrees, which according to several articles is far better and more robust methodolgy that using submodules which are frankly clumsy prone to not getting updated because git does not by default pull/fetch them.

I was merely asking for a quick walkthrough that works for windows git to create a subtree that can be merged back into the main repo.   Because the examples i have tried do not appear to work.

Comment: @davec - Sorry you find my attitude condescending.  Stopped reading at that, so I hope that was the most important point you wanted to make.

Comment: Successfully using Sub Modules on one of our projects, switching between branches without the submodule doesn't appear to cause any issues.

In fact it is all working quite well, maybe the articles i read which were very in depth were old articles.  But so far we are not seeing any issues.

Marking Mark's answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

My answer in short is NO do not use them they are down right dangerous as I had suspected in the first place.

Just google "should i use subrepos in git" "are git modules safe" "git submodule merge conflict" etc.

Whilst the advice was that sub modules is the answer and that they are safe i disagree; and so do many of the internet blogs from some fairly respected people.

Submodules seemed to work for a while but on merging development branches where the submodule was getting older various cracks started to show that i couldn't work out and that worried me.  I have 10 years and more of TFS, 3 years SVN and 1 year GIT so im reasonably capable with source control systems.  But for the life of me i could not figure this out nor could i 'confidently' merge the differences as the discrepancies between branches grew ever larger as time went on - even after i had synchronized and forced both submodule containers on all devs machines to be the same.

I could find nothing in GIT docs/blos/articles recommending against placing submodules inside of repositories and branching.  So that is what i did, but on merging the child feature branch back there were merge conflicts in files that hadn't been touched by the other parties, and worse still code changes that were much older were taken as newer, this was really worrying as you cant then trust the merge process.

I noted that this behaviour was only in the submodule branch, the actual dev branch merged in just fine, regardless of the wierd behaviour of the submodule.

In the end after a lot of wasted and painful nights I have very carefully merged the submodule back into the main branches and given up on the idea.

If i need to GIT good then i'm afraid I simply do not have the time to babysit submodules, so its back to dumb old git for me.